# Unused argument error in R code for function apply

Tags: r, apply

My code looks like this:

```
raw$hum_1<-raw$v_1_1
raw$hum_2<-raw$v_2_1
raw$hum_3<-raw$v_3_1
raw$hum_4<-raw$v_4_1
raw$hum_5<-raw$v_5_1
raw$hum_6<-raw$v_6_1
hum <- cbind(raw$hum_1, raw$hum_2, raw$hum_3, raw$hum_4, raw$hum_5, raw$hum_6)
raw$humsum<-apply(select(raw,names(raw)[grep('hum_',names(raw))]),1,sum)
ggplot(raw, aes(humsum))+geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

If I let it run, I get the error message:

> Error in select(raw, names(raw)[grep("hum_", names(raw))]) :    unused
>   argument (names(raw)[grep("hum_", names(raw))])

I do not find any mistake in it, especially since I do use the exact code before with another columns. I only exchanged numbers in raw$v_1_1 (etc.) and exchanged the suffix to "hum". Everything else is the same and it runs.

Furthermore, I can call the specific raw$hum_1 to raw$hum_6 without any issue. It is just this one apply function that crashes.

Comment: Try `dplyr::select` instead of just `select`.

Comment: `select` doesn't work that way, perhaps you want either `select_()` or `select(raw, starts_with("hum_"))`?